# Android: replace camera preview with image

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, appium

I'm doing black box automation testing (with appium & ruby) for app which use camera in few cases:
- taking photo
- scan QR code
- scan PDF code

I'm looking for a way to set image in to image preview to scan it. 
This should(ideally) word for both emulators and real devices.

Comment: I need to do a similar thing. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was willing to do the same for my app (which scann QR code), and the solution I used was to add an EditText (which appears only in test mode) to put the string, which corresponds to the QR code, and then handling the string as the result of the scan.

The problem with that solution is that you can't test the camera or the functions/methods you made to decode, but it's the only problem so if you are using a library (like ZXing) it's not a big deal, because I assume you want only the string that corresponds with the QR code.

Comment: That's good idea, but it's not about black box testing. And actually I don't have access to app source